# Laravel Socialite For Different Role User

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a project with two user roles.
I use the role_id field to distinguish roles from users.

When a user registers an account via manual input I make use of the hidden input to store the role_id.
But how can I save the role_id of users when they register for an account using a google account?

This is my controller

```
public function redirect($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function callback($provider)
{
    $getInfo = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    $user = $this->createUser($getInfo, $provider);
    auth()->login($user);

    return redirect()->to('/');
}

function createUser($getInfo, $provider){
    $user = User::where('provider_id', $getInfo->id)->first();

    if(!$user) {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $getInfo->name,
            'email' => $getInfo->email,
            'provider' => $provider,
            'provider_id' => $getInfo->id,
            'email_verified_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now()
        ]);

    }

    return $user;
}
```

This is my route

```
 Route::get('/auth/redirect/{provider}/', 'LoginUserController@redirect');
 Route::get('/callback/{provider}/', 'LoginUserController@callback' );
```

My View

```
a href="{{ url('/auth/redirect/google') }}" class="link-custom">{{ __('Google Account') }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to consider:

- Don't use hidden field to store a `role_id`. What's up with an user edit the code inline and change the `role_id`?
- You should to set up a default value for the `role_id` field, then all the users will have that default role.

Comment: Thank you for reminding @Louis, how about store role_id when used Socialite to sign up?

Comment: defining on the database a default id for the role_id?

Comment: yes, i have two different user role. how can we distinguish users from one another? @Louis

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear how you save the user role. Is it in a different table? On which basis do you assign roles to users? Nevertheless, you could always adjust the `createUser` method and save the other related info after creating the user. For example:

```
private function createUser($getInfo, $provider){
    $user = User::where('provider_id', $getInfo->id)->first();

    if(!$user) {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $getInfo->name,
            'email' => $getInfo->email,
            'provider' => $provider,
            'provider_id' => $getInfo->id,
            'email_verified_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now()
        ]);

        // Here you can save other stuff, 
        // E.g. the user role supposing it is saved in a different table
        UserRole::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'role_id' => 1 // Assigned role id
        ]);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: thanks for response before, but my question is how we store role_id for different  user. There is two user role_id, how can we distinguish users from one another? @hatef

Comment: For example: User X got role A, user Y got role B @hatef

Comment: I still can’t understand on what basis user gets assigned to a specific role? If it’s a hidden field in the UI who decides which role gets assigned to whom?

Comment: I using hidden field when user sign up manually not using google account. But when user sign via google account i can't use hidden field, because the method on route is get not post method. You can see my route and my view above @hatef

Comment: I'm not asking how you do it. I'm wondering on what basis. Let's say, user X signs up via frontend form. Why do you assign, role A to this user?

Comment: I use different page, for user with Role A and user with Role B @hatef

Comment: Ah so you have two sign up pages? And each of these pages has a Login with Socialite provider?

Comment: yes. i have two sign up page. Exactly.  User choice what role they want, and they will directed with different page @hatef

Comment: @barkah that's a bit tricky. One suggestion that comes to my mind is to let the user sign up using the Social network (Google), and after they can be redirected back to a page where they can choose their role.